# Auto creating data in db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am new in PHP and Laravel-5. I created project, which has DataController, Data model and it is connected to MySQL. Database has 2 columns: id and name.

> The problem: after page load need to auto-creation random amount of
>   data to db.

I want name to be a constant (name = "phone") +  add it's id to the end (phone 1, phone 2 ...). Something like `SELECT CONCAT('name', ' ', 'id') FROM 'table'`.
I think this logic should be in controller, but I don't know how to auto-generate data.

```
class DataController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $phones = Phone::all();
        return view('phones.index')-> with("phones", $phones);
    }
}
```

so I managed to solve main problem: automatically generate data to db by:

```
<?php 
  $pageWasRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';
  if($pageWasRefreshed ) {
     DB::table('phones')->insert([
     'name' => 'phone',
     ]);
  } 
?>
```

Now how can I add index to the end on the name, and how to add random amount of data?

```
DB::table('table')->insert([
         'name' => 'phone', + this id
]);
```

I think I should use join or leftJoin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the model where you want to generate the data in the db just see the User model that the laravel provide and simple use facades of DB i.e

DB::table('')->insert('')

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have such line on User model

Comment: Its becuse User model uses Eloquent ORM, you should go for query builder since its simple to understand. Here it is the tutorial.

Comment: @vikrammisty thx for the link, so I have to use DB::table('table')->insert(    ['name'=> 'phone']); to add data to my table, but I don't clearly understand where I should do it? in Controller public function store? And how to do that automatically?

Comment: simply create the model with artisan command like php artisan make:model <model_name> and write the db query over there and return the value to the controller. As u call that controller the query get executed.